# Can i assign multiple attribute set to a product in magento 1.5 ? if not how to handle this problem?

Tags: magento, attributes, entity-attribute-value

Can i assign multiple attribute set to a product in magento 1.5 ? if not how to handle this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can not.  A product has a single attribute set.  You "handle this problem" by creating a third attribute set that contains the attributes of the first two, and then maintaining each set.